# swift run loop 'NSFastEnumerationIterator.Element' (aka 'Any') is not convertible to 'UIView'

Tags: ios, uiview, swift3

```
var _buttons : NSMutableArray = []
override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {


    let location : CGPoint = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self)
    for subviews : UIView in _buttons {
        if subviews.frame.contains(location) {
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

I am doing this but it got a error `'NSFastEnumerationIterator.Element' (aka 'Any') is not convertible to 'UIView'`

I tried to replace  `for subviews : UIView in _buttons` to `for subviews : UIView in _buttons as [AnyObject]` but it doesn't work .

how do I proceed ?

Comment: What is `buttons`? Array of what?

Comment: Please show the code for when you set up the buttons array

Comment: yes, _buttons is a mutable array

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your collection like `var buttons: [UIView]`, to be sure that it contains only `UIView`s

Comment: sorry but the buttons is class of my custom UIButton . it got be a UIButton class not UIView

Comment: Then you need add `var buttons: [UIButton]`